# How to limit the numbers of processes to start?

Tags: c#, cmd

I wrote a program which uses Process.Start to call `cmd.exe` to call `qaac.exe` to covert a song to aac.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

It works but It only converts 1 song in a time. Now I want to make it always covert 4 songs in a time (run 4 process in a time).

Like there are 4 new process. If one is exit, Start a new one. Always fill 4 process in the background.

How to do that?

---

@Patrick Hofman
Thank you! It works!
But another problem I encountered.
I rewrite My code bellow:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(commands, 
        new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, 
        command => trans_aac(command));

        static void trans_aac(string command) {          

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.Exited += ProcessExited;
        proc.Start();
        while (!eventHandled) {

        }
        eventHandled = false;


    }
    static void ProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        eventHandled = true;
    }
```

Because the while loop, that makes the speed of conversion becomes really slow.
Any better way to make each process to wait for themselves to exit?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a `ThreadPool` and using threads to limit the processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is use the [Task Parallel Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx). You can set the maximum number of simultaneous executions:

```
string[] commands = new string[] { "mspaint", "notepad" };

Parallel.ForEach
( commands
, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }
, command => RunOneTask(command)
);
```

Fill an array or `List<string>` with the commands, and pass it into the method. You should put your current code into a separate method `RunOneTask` which takes one parameter: the command to execute.

Comment: @Kou: You removed the `p.WaitForExit();`. You shouldn't. Also, you set one boolean for 4 parallel tasks. That isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem. But I wonder there is anyway more smart.

```
static int i=0

static void send_covert_cmd() {
        if (i < commands.Count) {
            trans_aac(commands[i]);
            i++;
        }
}

//Start 4 process

sendcommand();
sendcommand();
sendcommand();
sendcommand();





static void trans_aac(string command) {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.Exited += ProcessExited;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        proc.Start();
}

static void ProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        send_covert_cmd();
}
```